# Using Jodd Lagarto to parse XML

Tags: xml, parsing, jodd, jodd-lagarto

I am using [Jodd Lagarto](http://jodd.org/doc/lagarto/) to parse some HTMLs. For some cases I also use [Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html), when I need to quickly process HTML. But now, I have some XMLs that I need to process. From the `TagVisitor` it looks like Lagarto may process XMLs as well (that would be awesome for me), but... I am not quite sure on how to do this.

Did anyone used Jodd Lagarto to process XMLs and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Lagarto for XML. I admit this is not so clear in the documentation, but there is way to enable [xml mode](http://jodd.org/doc/lagarto/lagarto-properties.html) for parsing. Here is a short example how:

```
LagartoDOMBuilder lagartoDOMBuilder = new LagartoDOMBuilder();
lagartoDOMBuilder.enableXmlMode();
Document doc = lagartoDOMBuilder.parse(xmlContent);
```

That's all! Method `enableXmlMode` sets several flags to make Lagarto parsing XMLs.

Even more, you can even use [Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html) for parsing XMLs, too! Here is how:

```
Jerry.JerryParser jerryParser = Jerry.jerry();
((LagartoDOMBuilder) jerryParser.getDOMBuilder()).enableXmlMode();
Jerry doc = jerryParser.parse(xmlContent);
```

Now you can use jQuery syntax and CSS selectors to filter your XML (aint that awesome, or what;)

Comment: Thank you for the Jerry hint!